# How to setup an event of a parent component to be called in a child component via code using vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 project that uses a component called revogrid to create a dashboard. This component receives another component to render a cell as a parameter. I would like to create a event inside the child component to change the value of the cell changing the datasource of the parent component. How to setup a event inside a child with code?

PARENT COMPONENT:

```html
<template>
  <div id="home">
    <v-grid theme="material" row-size="48" readonly="true" :source="rows" :columns="aux" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VGrid, { VGridVueTemplate } from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";
import Task from '../components/Task'; 

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      aux: [],
      columns: [
        {
          name: "Empresa",
          prop: "empresa",
          columnType: "string",
          size: 150,
        },
        {
          name: "Adiantamento",
          prop: "adiantamento",
          size: 150,
          cellTemplate: VGridVueTemplate(Task),
        },
        {
          name: "Sefip",
          prop: "sefip",
          size: 150,
          cellTemplate: VGridVueTemplate(Task),
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The component Task is a property inside the variable array columns. I would like to setup an event inside the task component that trigger a method inside the parent component.

I tried:

```js
Task.$emitter.on("update_cell", () => {
  alert("I am on the parent");
});
```

But doesn't works...

Answer (score 0):

aha,just figure out this requirement.

```js
// this is the default column configuration
{
    prop: 'columnAction',
    label: '',
    size: 75,
    minSize: 75,
    maxSize: 75,
    readonly: () => true,
    cellTemplate: VGridVueTemplate(EditableGridCellColumnAction),
}
```

if you need pass custom props or emits, you need

`import { h } from 'vue';`

and add some modification to `cellTemplate` like the following sample

```js
{
    prop: 'columnAction',
    label: '',
    size: 75,
    minSize: 75,
    maxSize: 75,
    readonly: () => true,
    cellTemplate: VGridVueTemplate(

        h(EditableGridCellColumnAction, {
            onDeleteRow: payload => {
            console.info(payload);
            },
        })
    ),
}
```

Comment: Is `onDeleteRow` fired by Revogrid or by the column with custom code?

Comment: ( I meanwhile solved it differently, see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue3 using Composition API I fixed it like this:

(but should also work with Vue2)

Parent component:

```js
[...]
const myFunction = () => {
   console.log("Hello World")
}

columns.value = [
  { prop: "foobar", size: 150 },
  {
    name: "my column",
    cellTemplate: VGridVueTemplate(MyComponent),
    prop: {
      myFunction: myFunction
    },
  },
]
[...]
```

In the child component (column):

```js
[...]
// ensure "prop" is definded in "props" - 
const props = defineProps(["prop"])


// execute the function with
props.prop.myFunction()

[...]
```

Since the function is executed in the scope of the parent component, it has access to all its properties and methods as well.